# Sharepoint Server 2016 Top-level menu stuck on subsites

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, top-link-bar, links

Has anyone encountered an issue of updating top level nav menu bar items? I believe I discovered either a bug or a familiar issue with it. Whenever I change the text (not the URL) of the items on the top level site, the text remains old on some, not all, of the subsites. Even though they inherit the top level navigation menu from the parent site.

Any ideas where to look it up?

Thank you
Alex

Comment: Have you refresh the subsite after updating top link bar in the parent site? If it doesn't work for you, please stop inheriting links from parent site and Use Links from Parent again to compare the result.

Comment: Hi @Julie_MSFT, thank you for suggestion. I have refreshed all of the subsites and they all still had the old text on the links. Also, stopped inheriting the links and enabled inheritance back on. Result is the same. Old text in subsites and the new nav bar wording on the main page of the top level site.

Comment: Whether all site collections occur this issue?Please create a new site collection and add some subsites to check the result.

Comment: I've created another subsite under the top-level site and it inherited the top navigation menu wording from a while back, again with old text. I've actually changed the link texts again and still all subsites are showing the old text.
Sorry, did you mean I should create a site collection in the Central Administration site like domain.name/new-site-collection? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can create a new site collection to check the results instead of creating a new subsite in the current problematic site collection.

Comment: I have noticed that a normal user without Admin privileges also sees the old top menu text on the top level site of the portal. Subsites are getting the old menu still, too